# In excel VBA, adding an undefined amount of numbers to an addition formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im struggling with creating code that is going to dynamically paste an undefined amount of variables into a formula. The part that im having trouble with is that the amount of values I have are undefined and being able to paste the values into the formula.

Example:

Calc A = (1 + 1) Ans = 2 Formula = 2

Calc B = (3 + 3) Ans = 6 Formula = 2 + 6

Calc C = (4 + 4) Ans = 8 Formula = 2 + 6 + 8

The benefit of this method is that I can see the audit trail of answers when I click into the formula.

Attempted code below

```
Dim Ans1 as Integer
Dim Ans2 as Integer

Ans1 = 2
Range("A1").Value = Ans1

Ans2 = 6
Range("A1").Formula = Ans1 + Ans2
```

Updated:

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim i As Long 'Base sheet
Dim ii As Long 'Moving sheet
Dim shtCount As Long
Dim ans As Variant
Dim ans2 As Variant

shtCount = Sheets.count - 1

For i = 7 To shtCount
For ii = i + 1 To shtCount

    If Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans = "" Then
    
    ans = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Value = ans
    
    ElseIf Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans <> "" Then
    
    ans2 = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ans = ans + ans2
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Value = ans
    
    End If

Next ii
Next i

End Sub
```

Update 09/14/21 5:15pm

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim i As Long 'Base sheet
Dim ii As Long 'Moving sheet
Dim shtCount As Long
Dim ans As Variant
Dim ans2 As Variant

shtCount = Sheets.count - 1

For i = 7 To shtCount
For ii = i + 1 To shtCount

    If Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans = "" Then
    
    ans = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula = "=" & ans
    
    ElseIf Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans <> "" Then
    
    ans2 = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula = "=" & ans & "+" & ans2
    
    ans = ans + ans2
    
    End If

Next ii
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Ans1 & "+" & Ans2`. But this very much sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: The challenge that I have is that sometimes there may be 2 answers,sometimes 3, sometimes 4, sometimes more and I want them all pasted within the formula

Comment: Well, if the idea is to be able to see the audit trail of answers, why not just color the cells involved in the summing and then put a change back color code in any worksheet event ?

Comment: Good thought but the data is coming from other workbooks.

Comment: If you store it as a value, it will get stored as a value. If you want to store the formula, you have to use the `Range.Formula` instead, But I only see `Range.Value` in your update.

Comment: Getting closer. Now just need it to keep adding the ans + ans2 + ans3 + ans4 dynamically somehow. updated code above

Comment: Why even use ans2? Did you try my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is this supposed to be some sort of sub called from something supplying the calculations?

For your updated formula, what about:

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim i As Long 'Base sheet
Dim ii As Long 'Moving sheet
Dim shtCount As Long
Dim ans As Variant

shtCount = Sheets.Count - 1

For i = 7 To shtCount
    For ii = i + 1 To shtCount
        If Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans = "" Then
            ans = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Value = "=" & ans
        ElseIf Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans <> "" Then
            ans = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
            Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula = Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula & "+" & ans
        End If
    Next ii
Next i

End Sub
```

or even:

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()
Dim i As Long 'Base sheet
Dim ii As Long 'Moving sheet
Dim shtCount As Long, ans As String, outRange As Range
Set outRange = Sheets("calc").Range("F5")
shtCount = Sheets.Count - 1
For i = 7 To shtCount
    For ii = i + 1 To shtCount
        If Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value Then
            ans = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
            If outRange = "" Then
                outRange.Value = "=" & ans
            Else
                outRange.Formula = outRange.Formula & "+" & ans
            End If
        End If
    Next ii
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I have so far. It works in adding the numbers together, it just doesnt store them in formula. Added in updated section