# Can anyone optimize this code so that I do not need 100 variables?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Can anyone help me optimize this code? I'm pretty sure there must be a better way to code this, but cant come up with it. I would like each variable to be dynamically available and be created only if needed. I really do not want to repeat this for all 100 variables.

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

Dim i As Long 'Base sheet
Dim ii As Long 'Moving sheet
Dim shtCount As Long
Dim ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5, ans6, ans7, ans8, ans9, ans10, ans11, ans12, ans13, ans14, ans15, ans16, ans17, ans18, ans19, ans20, ans21, ans22, ans23, ans24, ans25, ans26, ans27, ans28, ans29, ans30, ans31, ans32, ans33, ans34, ans35, ans36, ans37, ans38, ans39, ans40, ans41, ans42, ans43, ans44, ans45, ans46, ans47, ans48, ans49, ans50, ans51, ans52, ans53, ans54, ans55, ans56, ans57, ans58, ans59, ans60, ans61, ans62, ans63, ans64, ans65, ans66, ans67, ans68, ans69, ans70, ans71, ans72, ans73, ans74, ans75, ans76, ans77, ans78, ans79, ans80, ans81, ans82, ans83, ans84, ans85, ans86, ans87, ans88, ans89, ans90, ans91, ans92, ans93, ans94, ans95, ans96, ans97, ans98, ans99, ans100 As Variant

shtCount = Sheets.count - 1

For i = 7 To shtCount
For ii = i + 1 To shtCount

    If Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans1 = "" Then
    
    ans1 = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula = "=" & ans1
    
    
    ElseIf Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans2 = "" Then
    
    ans2 = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula = "=" & ans1 & "+" & ans2
    
    
    ElseIf Sheets(i).Range("B1").Value = Sheets(ii).Range("B1").Value And ans3 = "" Then
    
    ans3 = Abs(Sheets(i).Range("B8").Value - Sheets(ii).Range("B8").Value)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("calc").Range("F5").Formula = "=" & ans1 & "+" & ans2 & "+" & ans3

    End If

Next ii
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you summarize in broad terms what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm adding an additional elseif for every single variable, so the next line would be for ans4 and then repeat until ans100. In broad terms, I am trying to get the difference of 2 cells and then add them together having each value display in the formula. I would like to optimize the part where I am repeating each elseif from ans1 to ans100

Comment: Also related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170222/in-excel-vba-adding-an-undefined-amount-of-numbers-to-an-addition-formula?noredirect=1#comment122278650_69170222 Will give credit for both posts if able to optimize!

Answer (score 1):

### Using An Array Instead of Many Variables

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VbaLoopSheets()
    
    Const MaxExpectedAnswers As Long = 100
    Const FirstSheetIndex As Long = 7
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastSheetIndex As Long: LastSheetIndex = wb.Sheets.Count - 1
    Dim Answers() As String: ReDim Answers(1 To MaxExpectedAnswers)
    
    Dim wsb As Worksheet
    Dim wsm As Worksheet
    Dim b As Long ' Base Sheet
    Dim m As Long ' Moving Sheet
    Dim a As Long ' Answer
    
    For b = FirstSheetIndex To LastSheetIndex
        Set wsb = wb.Sheets(b)
        For m = b + 1 To LastSheetIndex
            Set wsm = wb.Sheets(m)
            If wsb.Range("B1").Value = wsm.Range("B1").Value Then
                a = a + 1
'                If a > MaxExpectedAnswers Then
'                    MsgBox "Too many answers.", vbCritical, "VBA Loop Sheets"
'                    Exit Sub
'                End If
                Answers(a) = Abs(wsb.Range("B8").Value - wsm.Range("B8").Value)
            End If
        Next m
    Next b

    With wb.Worksheets("Calc").Range("F5")
        If a = 0 Then
            .Value = ""
        Else
            If a < MaxExpectedAnswers Then
                ReDim Preserve Answers(1 To a)
            End If
            .Formula = "=" & Join(Answers, "+")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```